# Would a question about damages to a rental house be On Topic here

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm currently residing in a place that has suffered storm damages and I'm moving out because 3 years after the fact, nothing has been repaired.

I would like to find out if there is any rights / protection I lose upon leaving the house, that might be relevant to damages incurred during my tenure there.
As I know that you loose certain rights when you change your domicile to another house (most notably, it becomes very easy to evict someone if they are not properly domiciled AFAIK).

So to keep it short, I would like to know if there is any hidden danger upon leaving a rental house for the current tenants.

Would this be On Topic? Or is this too much a real case and not a learning / educational question to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely on topic; go ahead and ask it.  Of course we prefer that you make it both impersonal and as broadly interesting as possible, but as [this morning's discussion pointed out that doesn't necessarily mean you should leave out details that *happen* to be personal that could allow for better answers](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/questions-that-appear-to-seek-legal-advice).

Comment: I added the question, I'll see what kind of reception it receives. I am wholly unsure how to interpret the scope of this site, so feel free to give comments / edit the question if it strays too far.

Comment: @Reaces - Thank you for your caution.  Frankly, even if you have read only [this one policy Q&A](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) you should then feel free to post questions.  We offer a lot of guidance via flags, comments, and editing on the main site, and unlike what you may have experienced on other SE sites we try to keep them constructive and helpful.  The users here are very tolerant and understanding of the difficulty in delineating and staying inside "the line!"